Can monoclinic crystal have all sides equal?
Can a monoclinic crystal have all sides equal? Let's say we have a unit cell with all sides equal and two angles being 90° and third 60°. Such a unit cell is not included in the 7 Bravais lattices.

Bravais lattices are all about symmetry. The equality or inequality of such-and-such parameters is only a superficial sign of it. An occasional equality of parameters which are not required to be equal is possible, though rare.

@IvanNeretin so it is still monoclinic, right? Also, what about one with none sides equal and exactly one angle 90 deg?

Yes it is still monoclinic, and the other one is still triclinic. Now, multiple coincidences are too improbable to happen, but "monoclinic with beta angle of about $90^\circ$" is very much a thing, and it's genuinely hard to tell it from orthorhombic, and sometimes you just can't do that from cell parameters alone.

@IvanNeretin thanks for the reply. But they say that the Bravais lattices are mathematically derived and are the only ones possible. Then why is it improbable or hard to tell?

Yes they are the only ones possible. Monoclinic lattice is possible. So is orthorhombic. Sometimes monoclinic would have $\beta\approx90^\circ$. That's what we call a coincidence; they are rare, but possible. How would you tell it from orthorhombic? You won't, unless you look at the symmetry of the atoms' arrangement.

And what about the triclinic one with one angle 90 deg. Why it isn't included in Bravais lattices?

Because it is still triclinic.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Actually, the symmetry of a lattice dictates the unit cell parameter relationships. Son a monoclinic lattice cannot have the same parameter of an orthorhombic one, for example. But this is not true for crystal structures, that are a convolution of a lattice with basis. In some cases, a monoclinic structure can have 'orthorhombic' unit cell parameters (within the instrumental precision). In a lattice the points have all the same around, in a structure you have atoms and that's not always (quite ever) true
